# Postgres constraint: row with flag true must exist before false can

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, check-constraints

I have a database schema that looks something like this:

```
- Table: User
  - Column: id, primary key
- Table: UserAlias
  - Column: userId, foreign key
  - Column: isPrimary, boolean
```

I want to make it so that users have to have a primary alias, but cannot make a secondary one until they already have a primary one.

Is it possible to structure a constraint like this? Maybe a recursive foreign key constraint can work? Thanks!

Comment: If it can't be done directly in a constraint, it would be easy to do in an insert trigger.

Comment: What if the first record of an user is flagged as non-primary. Then the user could add a second one flagged as primary = true. Then the user has got two entries...

Comment: @404 you need to be careful when enforcing constraints with triggers https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/ due to race conditions.